# Proper way to Handle different screen sizes in react native ,

Tags: user-interface, react-native, screen-size

As , I developed a react native using physical device with screen size of 6 inch , it looked great and then when I tested with 5.5 it some what great , as still few components got spreader ! Then I tried with 4.3 inch , omg most of the components went beyond the screen . Then I googled , and found few packages which helps with screen size , it corrected the prop with 5.5 but still the prop persist at 4.3 inch !

I have converted most of the width and height as % , only padding is valued with int .

How to make the ui, responsively ! And one of my majore doubt is, I have created a top level View component with flex :1 and width and height with screen size. Even though , how come the sir goes beyond in small screen mobiles ?

As it should consider the screen size only bcoz , I have declared the width and height of screen by fetching the screen size. So every other components should be inside these values , but how comes it goes beyond ?

Please guide me with this , thanks in advance !

**Update**: Here is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { oneDayPlanSelected, monthlyPlanSelected } from '../../actions';
import { Text, Button, Card } from 'react-native-elements';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 
'react- 
native-responsive-screen';

const windowW= Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowH = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class PlanSelection extends Component {

onMonthlyPlanButtonPressed() {
    this.props.monthlyPlanSelected();
}

onOneDayPlanButtonPressed(){
    this.props.oneDayPlanSelected();
}

render () {

    const cowMilk = require('../../Images/cow_plan.png');
    const buffaloMilk = require('../../Images/buffalo_plan.png');

    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>

            <View style={styles.topContainerStyle}>
                <View style={styles.topBlueBoxContainer}>

                    <Text h4 style={styles.introTextStyle}>
                        Now, Choose how you wish to buy ? We have two 
plans.
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.imageContainerStyle}>
                        <Image 
                            source={ this.props.milkType === 'Cow Milk' ? 
cowMilk : buffaloMilk }
                            style={styles.topContainerImageStyle}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.choosePlanTextContainerStyle}>
                            <Text h4 style={styles.choosePlanTextStyle}>
                                Choose your plan.
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space- 
evenly'}}>

                <View>
                    <Card
                    containerStyle={{borderRadius: 5, width: windowW/2.2 
}} 
                    >
                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                <Text style= 
{styles.planNumberTextStyle}>1</Text>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, top: 40, 
fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Day</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ padding: 0 }}>
                            <Text style={styles.planDescpStyle}>Buy One 
day plan, by which we will deliver Cow Milk by Today.</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ padding: 0 }}>
                            <Text style={styles.planNameTextStyle}>One Day 
Plan</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <Button
                        backgroundColor='#2980b9'
                        rightIcon={{name: 'arrow-forward'}}
                        title='Buy'
                        raised
                        onPress= 
{this.onOneDayPlanButtonPressed.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </Card>
                </View>

                <View>
                    <Card
                    containerStyle={{borderRadius: 5,  width: windowW/2.2  
}} 
                    >
                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                <Text style= 
{styles.planNumberTextStyle}>30</Text>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, top: 40, 
fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Day's</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ padding: 0 }}>
                                <Text style={styles.planDescpStyle}>We 
have various monthly plans, Check In for more info</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ padding: 0 }}>
                                <Text style= 
{styles.planNameTextStyle}>Monthly Plan</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <Button
                        backgroundColor='#2980b9'
                        rightIcon={{name: 'arrow-forward'}}
                        title='Buy'
                        raised
                        onPress= 
{this.onMonthlyPlanButtonPressed.bind(this)}
                        />
                    </Card>
                </View>

            </View>
            <View style={styles.noteContainerStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.noteTextStyle}>We are excited ! Kindly 
select any one plan, and note that Monthly plan has various sub plans. For 
more info kindly choose the plan. </Text>
            </View>

        </View>
    );
   }
}

 const styles = {

containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    height: windowH,
    width: windowW, 
},
topBlueBoxContainer:{
    backgroundColor: '#f0ffff',
    height: windowH/1.7,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
},
imageContainerStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center'
},
topContainerImageStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    height: windowH/3
},
introTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingBottom: windowH/28,
    paddingLeft: windowW/8,
},
choosePlanTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 22
},
choosePlanTextContainerStyle:{
    alignSelf: 'center',
    padding: 15
},
planNameTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
},
planNumberTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 50,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#37BBE1'
},
planDescpStyle: {
    fontSize: 13,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    textAlign: 'center'

},
noteTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: '#b2bec3'
},
noteContainerStyle: {
    paddingTop: windowH/30,
    paddingLeft: windowW/25,
    paddingRight: windowW/10,
    bottom: windowW/22
}

};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    milkType: state.order.milktype
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,  
{oneDayPlanSelected,monthlyPlanSelected})(PlanSelection);
```

Ui in 4.3 Inch Screen :

[image]

Ui in 6 Inch screen :

[image]

Check the bottom of the screen, button components and few words are been overflowed. And i have been using react native elements for button and card, is this because of that ? Any idea and Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use % for providing width and height for components instead you should use Dimensions to get the width and height of the screen and then adjust the component style accordingly like marginTop, marginBottom, etc

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

OR,

you can do something like this

```
const windowW= Dimensions.get('window').width
const windowH = Dimensions.get('window').height
```

and use this as dims:{ height:windowH/2, width: windowW}

Moreover, you can adjust the width and height using windowW/2-30 etc..

Make sure to import Dimensions using-

```
import {StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: So by using this kind of dimensions ? It will auto resize according to the screen size ? And we should be using this for all components which required height and width right ?

Comment: try using it for parent component first.

Comment: and then adjust child components accordingly. Let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: I tried, but couldnt find any difference. Does this happens bcoz of font size ? does we need to make font also responsive by using rem or something ?

Comment: try using width to the text in which you are displaying font along with font size

Comment: you mean we should keep both fontsize and width ? i tried if the text has long , then it get shrinks !

Comment: try the same with paddings

Comment: what you mean correct flex setup? I kept a top level container with flex: 1, and changing the subcomponenets with respective alignments using padding , margin, top, bottom, left ! is this correct ?

Comment: ya, i know that and also i have implemented flex Direction where ever necessary

Comment: Check the flex direction in the parent component

Comment: oh yes and if you want to restrict your app to portrait mode or landscape mode you can do so by changing the android manifest file.

Comment: ya , i have already made the changes to keep portrait as default mode

Comment: Today, i have used the library called react-native-size-matters to scaled the values as per screen size. So ,the  changed code will included those values is it okay to post the code here ? how to send the code !

Comment: Undo the code and post the previous code here after clicking edit in your question

Comment: @Arvindh I have checked half of your code and firstly remove the width and height to the containerStyle and let it be flex:1 only and moreover if you are using headerLeft on top of the screen use react navigation createstacknavigator that will create the ui responsive to all screens by itself

Comment: Ya, using react navigation only with header enabled. And , i have tried removing width and height ! I think the prob is with react native elements , planning to change to nativebase

Comment: @Arvindh any progress with nativebase? post any link of screenshot in the comments here

Comment: @Arvindh let me know if you get any progress with nativebase as because I was also planning to work on nativebase

Answer (score 0):

try using [`flex`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox) properties (`flex`, `flexDirection`) and alignment with [`alignItems`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#alignitems) & [`jsutifyContent`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#justifycontent) alongwith desired margins & paddings.

Comment: As, previously i did the designs using these only !

Answer (score 0):

Although Dimensions like Harshit mentioned is an option, i don't like it, because when user changes direction from landscape to portrait for example, the values are not updated accordingly and you have an ugly ui.
I prefer setting it up with flex, and make sure that views with lots of content are ScrollViews(for smaller devices).
Also for horizontal space, if it is essential, you can set like 320-340 fixed dp for mobiles, and 820-840 fixed dp for tablets on container view..

Comment: In my case I restrict my app for portrait mode only. So that works for me.

Comment: I have asked the questioner to post the code let's inspect where he is doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My way is to use a combination of flex [to fill what i want no matter the size], with the aspectRatio property [to have the same aspect ratio in every screen no matter the size], and the library react-native-size-matters [to have the size units scaled accordint to the screen], so far, the ui is responsive to smartphones and tablets c:. Oh, and never, NEVER i use absolute values, ite makes the ui , as you said , overflow [xd].

Another neat tricks is just not use the height or width property, since they accomodate to their children. I have a bar, with `width:'100%'`, and inside i have a text component with `fontSize:moderateScale(30)` [react-native-size-matters], and also `padding:moderateScale(5)`. That simple setup renders the same bar , with responsive ui [it´s normal on small screens and bigger on big screens] 7u7

Comment: and i can even ignore width:'100%' , because if left alone the text fills all the width available. It's just a matter of knowing how to combine them and know how do every component / layout property behaves  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props

Comment: Actually, i have converted all absolute values to react-native-size-matters values like scale, vertical scale and moderate scale. But, still i am getting overflow with vertical dimensions, As only the bottom designs are overflowing than the screen in small sized phone !

Comment: What part of the component overflows ?, the whole component? , please post a screenshot in two different screen sizes it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok adding answer (Sorry for the delay)
I've found and fixed some problems with your styling

In your root view

```
containerStyle: {
    flex: 1, //This already tells that it should fill all space available, no need for width or height
    //height: windowH,
    //width: windowW, 
},
```

topContainerStyle doesn't exist in your code so i have no idea

> UPDATE 
>   2 hours later...

i've rebuilt the whole ui only to demonstrate how flex should be used, keep in mind that i have cut some text out, that's because if you need the text to be shown it needs to be short, or be wrapped in a scrollview . I've replaced the card, since it was giving some problems with flex , just style a view, give it some padding and you have a custom card.

I wanted to use react-native-size-matters but i've spent too much time in this , however, a quick tip is , if you can rotate the phone, and the ui is not completelly trash, you have a great UI! c:

https://snack.expo.io/rygco3J74

You can even implement your own button... i personally don't use react-native-elements because i like to do things my own ;) check the expo and try rotating the phone, you can even add a listener to the rotation and change the font size according to the rotation.

Comment: Thanks for this and I appreciate it , will check and will get you back !

Answer (score 0):

useWindowDimentions() will be useful there
https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions

Comment: Please add an example about how to use the API you are telling. External links might be broken in future.